# Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SSIS Script Task Error

Tags: ssis

Trying to create a Script task on VS 2008 on a SSIS Package. Keep getting error message:

" Registration information for this application needs to be updated. To update, log on as administrator and run this command: C:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\common7\ide\ 
vsta.exe /hostid SSIS_ScriptTask. Which I have tried numerous times, and un=install re-installed. Suggestions????

Comment: Did you spawn the cmd window with "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: Yes I did, and no dice.

Comment: @user3130669 Do you have multiple versions of Visual Studio installed?

Comment: Did you try running VS as administrator?